# Dropwizard 0.8 - enable CORS

Tags: java, cors, dropwizard

Does anyone know how to enable CORS for dropwizard 0.8? I can only find information about version 0.7 [here](http://jitterted.com/tidbits/2014/09/12/cors-for-dropwizard-0-7-x/).

apparently this didn't work

```
FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter(
                "CORS", CrossOriginFilter.class);
        // Add URL mapping
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class),
                true, "/*");
        filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM,
                "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
        filter.setInitParameter(
                CrossOriginFilter.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN_HEADER, "*");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders",
                "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With,Content-Length,Accept,Origin");
        filter.setInitParameter("allowCredentials", "true");
```

Comment: did you try setting the log level for org.eclipse.jetty.servlets to DEBUG ?

Answer (score 0):

The above should work. I've wrote a working gist with Unit Tests: https://gist.github.com/yunspace/07d80a9ac32901f1e149 that was tested against both 0.8.1 and 0.9.0-SNAPSHOT. Run it as a reference.

If you have issues try to setting your log level to DEBUG as @elec suggested:

```
loggers:
   org.eclipse.jetty.servlets: DEBUG
```

When CrossOriginFilter initialises it should print out the following log entry:

```
DEBUG [2015-05-07 11:55:39,247] org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter: Cross-origin filter configuration: allowedOrigins = *, allowedMethods = GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS, allowedHeaders = Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, preflightMaxAge = 1800, allowCredentials = true,exposedHeaders = ,chainPreflight = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for almost a week, I will post my code here, for those interested, basically the steps are the same:
 1. Include this on your application class
final FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = environment.servlets().addFilter("CORSFilter", CrossOriginFilter.class);

```
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");

    //filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, environment.getApplicationContext().getContextPath() + "*");
    // Configure CORS parameters
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin");
    filter.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,HEAD");
    // Add URL mapping
    filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), true, "/*");
```

2. When providing a Response on current resource explicitly include your options.

   ```
   return Response.status(status)
           .entity(new MessageResponse(this.counter.incrementAndGet(), message, response))
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin.isPresent() ? origin.get():"*")
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", methods)
           .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, header-task")
           .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
           .encoding("UTF-8")
           .allow(allow)
           .build();
   ```